# Jquery range slider (set min and max values)

Tags: jquery

I do not know how to set min and max values

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>

  $(function() {

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({

      range: true,

      values: [ 75, 300 ],

      slide: function( event, ui ) {

        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );

      }

    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +

      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

  });

  </script>

</head>

<body>



<p>

  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>

  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">

</p>



<div id="slider-range"></div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, retag your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its a joke? Have you seen manual?
https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max
just add params min and max like that:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
  max: 50
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used same code, and i also wanted to set minimum and maximum slider range manually.
finally i found the solution:

write your minimum and maximum values in hidden `<input>` field.
Html:

```
 <input type="text" id="d_amount" style="border: 0; color: #ffffff; font-weight: normal;" value="20 - 100" hidden/>
```

jquery:

```
var pvalue = $('#d_amount').val().split('-');
        var min = parseInt($.trim(pvalue[0]));
        var max = parseInt($.trim(pvalue[1]));
      $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: min,
            max: max,
            values: [min, max ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {  $( "#amount" ).val( "Rs." + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Rs." + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            
            },
            stop: stopslider
      });
      function stopslider(){
        
        var min = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )
        var max = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )
        console.log(min+"---"+max);
        var url = "{{ route('product.filter.price') }}";
        
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {cat: path, max_v: max, min_v: min},
            success:function(res){ 
              $('.product-men').remove();    
              $('.products-right').append(res.fout);
              $('.single-pro').append(res.lout);
            }
          });
      }
        $( "#amount" ).val( "Rs." + $.trim($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )) + " - Rs." + $.trim($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )) );
      
      });
```